# The JSLint extension for VS2012 doesn't recognize JSON

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, jslint

I just installed the JSLint extension for VS2012 and I'm getting exceptions for some JSON settings files that I use. Using the default settings this caused my builds to be automatically cancelled so I had to turn off the option to cancel builds because of JSLint errors. There is no reason JSON should not be recognized, since it is valid Javascript. The exceptions that I get say "Expected: ';'". I checked the JSLint options and I couldn't find an option to fix this, does anyone know of a way? A sample settings file is:

```
{
  "SharePath": "\\\\172.26.168.60\\main\\Temp\\Webclient",
  "LocalFilePath": "C:\\\\Builds\\WebClient",
  "BuildCount": "10", 
  "AppVersions": [
    {
      "VersionName": "hotfix",
      "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_hotfix"
    },
    {
      "VersionName": "main",
      "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_main"
    },
    {
      "VersionName": "master",
      "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_master"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the extra strict rules of JSLint as dictated by the great Douglas Crockford, All expressions should have a trailing semicolon at the end.  The declaration of a JSON object is an expression -- add a semicolon to the end and you should be golden. While JavaScript itself does not force you to end every expression with a semicolon, it can cause compilation issues in some weird cases if you do not do this, so JSLint forces you to do it. You should recognize that by using JSLint you are agreeing to use a more strict subset of JavaScript then the on dictated by the spec for the language. The tradeoff however is that this subset is less error prone that the full set of the language and therefore safer to use.

```
{
  "SharePath": "\\\\172.26.168.60\\main\\Temp\\Webclient",
  "LocalFilePath": "C:\\\\Builds\\WebClient",
  "BuildCount": "10", 
  "AppVersions": [
    {
      "VersionName": "hotfix",
      "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_hotfix"
    },
    {
      "VersionName": "main",
      "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_main"
    },
    {
      "VersionName": "master",
      "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_master"
    }
  ]
}; // <--- ';' HERE
```

The reason  that the online JSLint seems to pass the object here, while the VS2012 JSLINT does not is that the JSLint online is treating the object as JSON object and only checking that part of the object. The VS2012 you are using is treating you're JSON file as a full javascript file and treating that JSON object as part of a larger JS expression (as all JSON objects must eventually be) therefore it is checking more things then the online JSLint editor is. (It is checking expression syntax where the online JSLint is not.  In simpler terms the JSLint online tool defaults to a simpiler mode then the VS2012 is running. I have updated my answer to a for that will force the onlint JSLint to to run the full JS expression check. Try pasting this into the onlie tool and see what happens. (HINT JSLint isnt happy)

```
var test2 = "Hey JSLint Im a JS file, not a JSON object danm it!"; 
{
    "SharePath" : "\\\\172.26.168.60\\main\\Temp\\Webclient",
    "LocalFilePath" : "C:\\\\Builds\\WebClient",
    "BuildCount" : "10",
    "AppVersions" : [
        {
            "VersionName": "hotfix",
            "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_hotfix"
        },
        {
            "VersionName": "main",
            "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_main"
        },
        {
            "VersionName": "master",
            "BuildPath": "\\\\10.18.0.53\\Builds\\WebClient_master"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The extension still doesn't recognize it, however. Also, if I paste the JSON as-is into JSLint.com it says it is perfect.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain why you are seeing this.

Comment: Thanks again, that makes sense. I guess the makers of the JSLint don't like the idea of a JS file that contains only a stand-alone object, which is what I am (ab)using it for. Basically I've replaced app.config with settings.js since it is so simple to create a custom object and parse if from JSON (but that is a topic for a different thread).